# Custom response decorator for model view set in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to customize my response in `CollectionViewSet`
for each `http` method. response would be different `message` and `status` code

## Problem,

`list`, `create`, `update` method are identical to it's `parent` except `delete` method which has some extra logic

```
# Working V-1
class CollectionViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Collection.objects.annotate(
        products_count=Count('products')).all()
    serializer_class = CollectionSerializer

    def generate_response(self, message, status_code, data=[]):
        response_data = {
            'message': message,
            'status': status_code,
            'data': data
        }

        return Response(response_data, status=status_code)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        collections = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(collections, many=True)

        return self.generate_response('Data fetched successfully',
                                      status.HTTP_200_OK, serializer.data)

    # no special logic it's identical to (super().create()) method
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return self.generate_response('Data created successfully',
                                      status.HTTP_201_CREATED, serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return self.generate_response('Data updated successfully',
                                      status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED, serializer.data)

    def destroy(self, request, pk):
        collection = get_object_or_404(Collection, pk=pk)
        if collection.products.count() > 0:

            return self.generate_response('collection cannot be deleted because it includes one or more products.',
                                          status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

        collection.delete()

        return self.generate_response('Data deleted successfully',
                                      status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I am trying to have some way to `decorate` the `CollectionViewSet` class
so that I can utilize full feature of `ModelViewSet` and able to get `response` as before

```
@generate_custom_response
class CollectionViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Collection.objects.annotate(
        products_count=Count('products')).all()
    serializer_class = CollectionSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
   
    def destroy(self, request, pk):
        collection = get_object_or_404(Collection, pk=pk)
        if collection.products.count() > 0:

            return self.generate_response('collection cannot be deleted',
                                          status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

        collection.delete()

        return self.generate_response('Data deleted successfully',
                                      status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Before `# Working V-1`

I also tried to change `to_representation` method in `CollectioSerailizer` to change the format of a `response` dynamic it was working as expected except when I try to get the fetch the `list` of `collection` i get repeated `response` from `to_representation` method

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'products_count']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        
        http_method = self.context['request'].method

        (status_code, message) = (
            (status.HTTP_200_OK, 'fetched') if http_method == 'GET' else
            (status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED, 'updated') if http_method == 'PUT' else
            (status.HTTP_201_CREATED, 'created') if http_method == 'POST' else
            (status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, 'deleted'))
        
        response = {
            'message': message,
            'status': status_code,
            'data': ret
        }

        return response

#problem in response => 
[
    {
        "message": "fetched",
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Semiconductors",
            "products_count": 74
        }
    },
    {
        "message": "fetched",
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Major Pharmaceuticals",
            "products_count": 74
        }
    },
    {
        "message": "fetched",
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "Homebuilding",
            "products_count": 81
        }
    },
    {
        "message": "fetched",
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "Major Banks",
            "products_count": 83
        }
    }
]
```